Draw a circle with periodic boundary conditions matplotlib
I am doing a project that involves lattices. A point of coordinates (x0, y0) is chosen randomly and I need to color blue all the points that are in the circle of center (x0, y0) and radius R and red all the other points and then draw a circle around.
The tricky part is that there is periodic boundary conditions, meaning that if my circle is near the left border then I need to draw the rest of it on the right side, the same goes for up and down.
Here is my code that plots the lattice, I have managed to color the points depending on whether or not they are in the circle but I am yet to draw the circle.
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class lattice:

    def __init__(self, L):
        self.L = L
        self.positions = np.array([[[i, j] for i in range(L)] for j in range(L)])
    
    def draw_lattice(self, filename):
        X = self.positions[:, :, 0].flatten()
        Y = self.positions[:, :, 1].flatten()
        plt.scatter(X, Y, s=10)
        plt.xticks([])
        plt.yticks([])
        plt.title("Lattice")
        plt.savefig(filename)
    
    def dist_centre(self):
        x0, y0 = np.random.randint(0, self.L), np.random.randint(0, self.L)
        self.c0 = (x0, y0)
        self.distance = np.zeros((self.L, self.L))

        for i in range(self.L):
            for j in range(self.L):
                x = self.positions[i, j, 0]
                y = self.positions[i, j, 1]
                # Distance with periodic boundary conditions.
                Dx = -self.L/2 + ((x0-x)+self.L/2)%self.L
                Dy = -self.L/2 + ((y0-y)+self.L/2)%self.L
                dist = np.sqrt(Dx**2 + Dy**2)
                self.distance[i, j] = dist

    def draw_zone(self, filename, R):
        colormap = np.where(self.distance <= R, "blue", "red").flatten()

        X = self.positions[:, :, 0].flatten()
        Y = self.positions[:, :, 1].flatten()
        plt.clf()
        plt.scatter(X, Y, s=10, color=colormap)
        plt.xticks([])
        plt.yticks([])
        plt.title("Lattice")
        plt.savefig(filename)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    L = 10
    R = 3
    filename = "test.pdf"
    latt = lattice(L)
    latt.draw_lattice(filename)
    latt.dist_centre()
    latt.draw_zone(filename, R)

The formula for the distance is modified because of the periodic boundary conditions.


A workaround would be to always define a bigger lattice and then to take your actual lattice from the big one after colouring

The comment from Tino_D gave me the answer. I imagined a bigged lattice, my lattice and 8 lattices surrounding it and drew a total of 9 circles with a centers that were translated to another sub lattice and then I restricted my plot to the original lattice.
    def draw_zone(self, filename, R):
        colormap = np.where(self.distance <= R, "blue", "red").flatten()

        X = self.positions[:, :, 0].flatten()
        Y = self.positions[:, :, 1].flatten()

        x0, y0 = self.c0
        centers = [(x0-L, y0-L), (x0-L, y0), (x0-L, y0+L),
                   (x0, y0-L), (x0, y0), (x0, y0+L),
                   (x0+L, y0-L), (x0+L, y0), (x0+L, y0+L)]
        
        plt.clf()

        for (x,y) in centers:
            circle = plt.Circle((x, y), R, alpha=0.2, color="grey")
            plt.gca().add_patch(circle)

        plt.scatter(X, Y, s=10, color=colormap)
        plt.xticks([])
        plt.yticks([])
        plt.xlim(0, self.L-1)
        plt.ylim(0, self.L-1)
        plt.title("Lattice")
        plt.savefig(filename)



very nice, always great to see someone answering their question and learning in the process. I would like to ask you if you would like to consider taking a different distance metric to define your circle. As currently, I guess the Manhattan distance is taken, where we basically see a square overlayed with a + mark. Is this intentional?

I used the euclidian distance in that case, but you can change to whatever you like in the code. Change the line in the dist_centre function where dist is defined (here dist = sqrt(Dx² + Dy²), for the Manhattan distance you would have abs(Dx) + abs(Dy)
